# Can I see what network key I use to connect to my router?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, router

On a WindowsXP laptop which is automatically connecting to the router, is there a way to see what key was entered previously?

I've seen all the answers about having to access the router config page but can I find what key I previously entered - I don't have the router password and it's not my router so I cannot reset it; the owner is ill so cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) will extract the key used.

note that XP translates the passphrase to the hex key value, so you will not be able to see what passphrase was used. (Vista and later do not suffer this issue)